# libboost1.46-all-dev

Tags: ros, linuxmint, debian, libboost

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am doing an install on LMDE, which uses the latest debian repositories. rosinstall fails when it cannot install libboost1.42-all-dev. libboost1.46-all-dev is available in the repository. Is there any way to get rosinstall to use the updated package? Or do I have to find and install all of the libboost1.42-all-dev dependancies?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11643/libboost1.46-all-dev/) by [thericcer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1261/thericcer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 151 on 2011-10-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Figured it out myself.

Had to change the rosdep.yaml file in the ros package.
Changed the dependancy from libboost1.42-all-dev to libboost1.46-all-dev. That was all that was needed.

Hopefully it saves someone else hours of headache :-P

---

Originally posted by [thericcer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1261/thericcer/) with karma: 151 on 2011-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1